Разве что кроме
Нужна ли запятая перед "кроме" в предложении:

Все пошли в лес, разве что кроме совсем маленьких детей.


Правильно:
Все пошли в лес, разве что кроме совсем маленьких детей.
Пояснение
Разве – частица со значением сомнения, неуверенности, допущения вариантов, исключений. В данном случае относится к речевому обороту с предлогом КРОМЕ.
РАЗВЕ. I. частица.
 3. (обычно со сл.: лишь, только, вот, чуть, что и т.п.). 
 При выражении допущения, возможности чего-л. или 
 ограничения чего-л. чем-л.: может быть только, может быть 
 лишь. В кино я люблю р. комедию. Это дерево трухлявое, 
 годится р. лишь на дрова. Придут все, кроме р. одного.

Карта слов
Ну разве что кроме каких-то особых мастериц, обученных тонкому ремеслу – златошвеек, например.
Это интересно: Существует ли историческая связь между приставкой "раз-" и словом "разве"?
